# using function arguments inside .each() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get certain arguments in a function and when i try to use them inside .each() which loops through my ajax response. when i log the argument inside the each function i get undefined.

```
function updateCandidateDetails(data,can_id){

    var candidate_id = can_id;
    var updated_name,updated_phone,updated_email;

    $.each(data,function(key,value){
        $.each(value,function(index,titleObj){

        var updated_name = titleObj.name;
        var updated_phone = titleObj.phone;
        var updated_email = titleObj.email;

        console.log(updated_name);
        console.log(candidate_id);

    var panel = $('div#'+candidate_id+'.panel');
    panel.find('p#card_name').val();                
    panel.find('div.card_details p#card_phone').val(updated_phone);               
    panel.find('div.card_details small#card_email').val(updated_email);
        });
    });

}
```

Here is my html

```
<div class="panel" id="{{$candidate->id}}">
  <div class="card_details">
    <b><p id = "card_phone">{{$candidate->phone}}</p></b>
    <b><small id="card_email">{{$candidate->email}}</small></b><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

With can_id i am not able to update the value using val() function since finding the parent panel needs `candidate_id`

Comment: May be you should post the html as well.

Comment: The question has been updated with html

Comment: Provide your Ajax response here

Comment: Is `panel.find('#card_phone').val(updated_phone); ` working? Also, if this div is a repeating one, then you should consider using class instead of id.

Comment: Where does the titleObj come from?

Comment: And it should be `.text()` not `.val()` for updating text inside `p`. - `panel.find('#card_phone').text(updated_phone);`